# Is availability of HDFS file being overwritten by put command 100%?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am using

```
echo 'new_hoge' | hdfs dfs -put -f - /output_path/hogefile
```

to overwrite `/output_path/hogefile` but I want to ensure it to be available(either of the result is fine) for any read request in the meanwhile.

Is this operation atomic so that I need not worry about it? If not, how this is normally achieved in practice?

HDFS documentation in the [this](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/filesystem/introduction.html#Core_Expectations_of_a_Hadoop_Compatible_FileSystem) document do not say about the atomicity feature with overwrite operation about so I assume this is not provided by the filesystem. Wasn't able to locate in Hadoop filesystem [code](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/site/markdown/filesystem/filesystem.md#-fsdataoutputstream-createpath-) either.

Comment: All read requests that are accessing the namenode before the file is written will be sent prior block locations for the file. You're not overwriting a file, you're overwriting meta data for a file reference

Comment: Thanks. If i understand correctly, as we are just overwriting the meta file on the name node, the availability should be 100%. I just wish the documentation should have stated this thing.

Comment: Well, HDFS is like an append only file system. Therefore, you're writing new blocks somewhere for any new file, then the namenode updates for the new location. Old blocks would get discarded at some point, but I'm not sure the implications on pending read operations